# SVN (svnserve) virtual root --root= not recognized

Tags: svn

I'm running SubVersion 1.6.11 on RHEL6.

I added a new svn repo like so: `svnadmin create /var/svn`
I run svnserve as the svn user like: `svnserve -d --root=/var/svn`
The repository is setup like /var/svn/projectname/branch

I can check out files like this `svn co svn+ssh://svnhost/var/svn/projectname localco`
But this shouldn't work because svnserve is set with --root=/var/svn

I should be able to do `svn co svn+ssh://svnhost/projectname localco`
But get an error "svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://svnhost/projectname'"

Why is the virtual root not working?

Comment: I suppose this could also fit ServerFault or Superuser, but since there are 15000 subversion tagged questions on here, I think this is the best place for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svn+ssh handles the whole transaction including writing and reading the files so it ignores the --root parameter in svnserve.

Here is how to fix it over at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/58190/subversion-path-differences-for-svn-and-svnssh) --

Basically you just make svnserve into a script that calls svnserve with the proper variables.

Answer (score 0):

`--root`, if used, defines **common parent** of all repositories, served by **pure** svnserve. You have repo in root location, it's wrong